# animation nodes mix vector doesnt work

Tags: animation-nodes

How i can fix it?
I trying to make some morph with metaballs
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some nodes just don't accept lists. Nodes that accepts lists are said to be *vectorized*, on this case, this not isn't vectorized. You can either use another node to achieve the same result, or use a loop as follows:

[image: Node Tree]

Comment: @StanislavVonSyktyvkarian Please accept the answer if it answers your question.

Comment: Maybe you can achieve same results with offset nodes